# How do i align boxes like this

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align 3 boxes and 2 images.

2 boxes vertically with there is an img between

3rd box standing right of them with an arrow img pointing it like this:
[image]

Example box css:

```
.box{
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #8C8C8C;
margin:0 auto;
border: solid 3px #8B0000;


}
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: You should show us something that you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

Use `flexbox` and divide to 3 section(3 `div`s) inside the `wrap` div

```css
.wrap{
display:flex;
}
.box{
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #8C8C8C;
margin:0 auto;
border: solid 3px #8B0000;
}
.img1 img{
  width: 80px;
  height: 150px;
}
.part2 img{
    width: 150px;
  height: 80px;
}
.part2,.part3{
margin-top: 100px;
}
.part3 .box{
    margin-left: 40px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="part1">
    <div class="box">

    </div>
      <div class="img1">
         <img src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg"/>
     </div>
      <div class="box">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="part2">
    <img src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <div class="part3">
      <div class="box">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have constant number of elements. (3 boxes and 2 images with fixed width and height), you can create wrapper box with relative position, then add position absolute to child nodes and write needed positions. for example:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}

.child-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox to position your boxes by rows and columns.

```css
#cont1 {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}

.box{
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #8C8C8C;
border: solid 3px #8B0000;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="box">Box 2
</div>
<div id="cont1">
<div> IMG1 </div>
<div> IMG2 </div>
<div class="box">Box 3</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
Box 1
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use the float/clear attribute:

```
.box1{
float: left;
}
.box2{
float: right;
}
.image{
float: left;
}
.box3{
float: left;
}
```

Afterwards just use position: relative  within your classes fix the positioning.